# Find number of occurrences of substring

Tags: c++, string, performance, find, find-occurrences

I have a small problem. I'm solving one programming task, but have a problem with it. It is simple one, but time limit make it a bit harder.

> Find number of occurrences of substring. You will be given M - length
>   of substring; substring to find, N - length of base string; base
>   string.
>    M <= 100 000
>    N<= 200 000
>
> Input
>
> 10
>       budsvabbud
>       79
>   uaahskuskamikrofonu**budsvabbud**nebudlabutkspkspkspmusimriesit**budsvabbudsvabbud**nel
>
> Output
>    3

I tried to use using build-in function find,but it wasn't fast enough:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int occurrences = 0;
    string::size_type start = 0;
    string base_string, to_find;
    cin >> n >> to_find >> n >> base_string;
    while ((start = base_string.find(to_find, start)) != string::npos) {
        ++occurrences;
        start++;; // see the note
    }
    cout << occurrences << endl;
}
```

So I tried to write my own function, but it was even slower:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>
#include<queue>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, m;
    string to_find;
    queue<int> rada;  
    int occurrences = 0;
    cin >> m >> to_find >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        char c;
        scanf(" %c", &c);
        int max = rada.size();
        for (int j = 0; j < max; j++)
        {
            int index = rada.front();
            rada.pop();
            if (c == to_find[index])  
            {
                if (++index == m) {
                    occurrences++;
                }
                else
                    rada.push(index);
            }
        }
        if (c == to_find[0])
        {
            if (1 == m)
                n++;
            else
                rada.push(1);
        }
    }
    cout << occurrences << endl;

}
```

I know some people did this in 0 ms, but my first code needs more than 2000 ms and the second one a lot more than that. Have you any ideas how to solve this? 
Thanks.

EDIT:
Limits of length:

M <= 100 000   - length of substring

N<= 200 000    - lenght of base string

Comment: 2000 mSec! how long is the input ?

Comment: @HumamHelfawi Sorry, I forgot to write it. I will edit my question.

Comment: Have you enabled optimization?  Do you really mean 2000 milliseconds - I'd be surprised at even a debug build taking that long.

Comment: For fast searching in large files, something like Boyer-Moore is probably an order of magnitude (or more) faster - but it's not likely to be worth it for 79 characters.

Comment: Yeah, I mean 2000 milliseconds. But not for input I gave as example. There could be input with length 200 000.

Comment: Aahh.  Boyer-Moore *is* going to be worth it for 200K characters - but I don't know if it works well for such huge search strings

Comment: It might be worth doing a Boyer-Moore search for the first 1000 characters, and then a brute-force comparison for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The algorithm you presented is an O(M*N), where N is the length of the text and M is the length of the searched world. Usually, also the libraries implement the naive algorithm. However, there is an algorithm by Knuth, Morrison and Pratt, which does it in a O(M+N) time. See, e.g., Wikipedia [Knuth-Morrison-Pratt Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm). It has some variations which might be easier to implement like [Boyer-Moore-Horsepool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm).

Comment: This. If the string you're searching in is 200k of `aaaa...` and the string you're searching for is 100k of `aaaa...b` (99999 a's then 1 b) then the complexity of your search is going to be 200000 * 100000 which is huge. This is because, using any naive implementation, you'll try to match your search string at position 1, then matching 99999 a's then fail to match a b. You then move to position 2 and repeart the failure. At each position in the search string you have to do 99999 matches. KMP solves this problem nad has a compexity O(m+n) instead of O(m * n).

Answer (score 1):

## Safe version

```
static size_t findOccurences(const char * const aInput, const char * const aDelim)
{
    if (aInput == 0x0 || aDelim == 0x0)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Argument(s) null");
    }

    const size_t inputLength = strlen(aInput);
    const size_t delimLength = strlen(aDelim);

    size_t result = 0;

    if (delimLength <= inputLength && delimLength > 0)
    {
        size_t delimIndex = 0;

        for (size_t inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < inputLength; inputIndex++)
        {
            if (aInput[inputIndex] != aDelim[delimIndex])
            {
                delimIndex = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                delimIndex++;

                if (delimIndex == delimLength)
                {
                    delimIndex = 0;
                    result++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

## Unsafe version

```
static size_t unsafeFindOccurences(const char * const aInput, const char * const aDelim)
{
    const size_t inputLength = strlen(aInput);
    const size_t delimLength = strlen(aDelim);

    size_t result = 0;
    size_t delimIndex = 0;

    for (size_t inputIndex = 0; inputIndex < inputLength; inputIndex++)
    {
        if (aInput[inputIndex] != aDelim[delimIndex])
        {
            delimIndex = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            delimIndex++;

            if (delimIndex == delimLength)
            {
                delimIndex = 0;
                result++;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

## Results safe

```
          x86        x64
Debug     5501ms     5813ms
Release   3889ms     3998ms
```

## Results unsafe

```
          x86        x64
Debug     5442ms     5564ms
Release   3074ms     3139ms
```

Compiled with Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2015 (v140) toolset under Windows 10 x64 Pro.

Using [this](http://generator.lorem-ipsum.info/) input. Searching for 'ad' and 1.000.000 iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I try this code in debug mode without any optimization and it took **11 mSec**. VS.NET 2013 , Intel Core i7:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    int occurrences = 0;
    string::size_type start = 0;
    string base_string, to_find;
    base_string.reserve(200000);
    to_find.reserve(100000);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        base_string.push_back('a');
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        base_string.push_back('b');
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        to_find.push_back('b');
    }
    auto start_s = clock();
    while ((start = base_string.find(to_find, start)) != string::npos) {
        ++occurrences;
        start++;; // see the note
    }
    auto stop_s = clock();
    std::cout << (stop_s - start_s) / double(CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 1000;
    cout << occurrences << endl;
    std::getchar();
}
```

There is a problem in compiler, configuration, your machine, but in your code.

Comment: This is task from website and I sent this code to be checked there as well. I just got a result - Time limit exceeded - and a time which my code needed :1.in OK 0 ms
2.in OK 0 ms
3.in OK 0 ms
4.in OK 1 ms
5.in OK 164 ms
6.in OK 45 ms
7.in TLE 1811 ms

Comment: Try making `base_string` 200,000 'a's and the `to_find` string 99,999 'a's and then a single 'b'. Then remeasure...

Comment: I did this.. and it went from 01 to 14440